# I am unable to get custom prompts to work in zsh

Tags: macos, zsh

I want to set a custom prompt in zsh. I want my prompt to show the current k8s context.

I tried this:

```
kubectx()
{
  export PROMPT="$(kubectl config current-context) "
}

precmd_functions=[ 'kubectx' ]
```

and this:

```
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
kubectx()
{
  echo "running..."
  CURRENT_CONTEXT="$(kubectl config current-context)"
}

precmd_functions=[ 'kubectx' ]

PROMPT="${CURRENT_CONTEXT} $"
```

And also this

```
export PROMPT="$(kubectl config current-context) "
```

But in both cases, I get a prompt that is fixed to when `.zshrc` was run, and it does not refresh when for eg, i switch kube contexts.

I tried to read the precmd documentation but could not find out what to do to enable this customization in zsh shell.

Has anyone shown how to script or program this?

Comment: The prompt does not change magically byitself. If you do on the command line a `PROMPT=foo`, and the prompt immediately after is set back to the old value defined in .zshrc, you must have defined some callback function (similar to `precmd` ... there are many such functions) which sources your .zshrc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried precmd also, but it did not work. It only runs at shell startup. Is there some option I need to set?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean by _only runs at shell startup_. If the _precmd_ setting is not active anymore after the shell started, there must something in your startup scripts, which disables it; but I don't know why you _tried_ it; I never suggested that you should use _precmd_, unless you want do.

Comment: In the second and third attempt, because of the use of double quotes, the prompt is indeed fixed the first time you evaluate it. In the first attempt, the double quotes should be OK, because setting the prompt happens inside the precmd function. I wonder whether the precmd really executed. For debugging, you could write inside `kubectx` the value of $PROMPT to  stderr. Note that with this approach, the prompt is adjusted, after you have pressed enter, and before the command is actually executing.

Comment: BTW, your assignment to `precmd_functions` is wrong. I'm not sure whether this really **is** a special variable for zsh (my manpage does not mention it), but if it exists, I bet that it must be an array, i.e. `precmd_functions=( kubectx )`.

Comment: Ah, I just found the description of `precmd_functions` (it is in chapter _Hook Functions_ in the zshmisc man page), and indeed, it is an array, so you have to assign it as array. In you set it as environment variable to the string `[` and then run _kubectx_, and this really does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`precmd_functions` must be an **array**! Therefore you have to use

```
precmd_functions=( kubectx )
```

Comment: Ah! I forgot that array syntax was `()` and not `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

BTW I found the issue. The issue was that i was using double quotes.

If I use single quote instead, it works.

```
PROMPT='$(kubectl config current-context)'
```

Even escaping the dollar works with double quotes.

```
PROMPT="\$(kubectl config current-context)"
```